# how to generate .tex file from build folder

Tags: texmaker

I lost the .tex file of a report written many years ago. However, I still have the build folder containing: .aux .bbl .blg .dvi .log .out .pdf .spl. Is there a way to use the contents of this build folder for the generation of the corresponding .tex file? This .tex file has to be used as a chapter of a book.

Comment: basically no, if you have the pdf, save the text and re-add the tex markup

Comment: Is it possible to find the path of figures from one of the files in the folder build?

Comment: the log file may give hints about image files included (but not the full path just the relative paths based on the search tree used at the time)